# Bitnami SonarQube when accessed via URL routes to the IP instead

Tags: amazon-web-services, sonarqube, bitnami

I have recently installed bitnami sonarqube 8.6 on AWS, and then configured DNS to serve it via my domain. I have also gone to sonar settings and changed the default host to point to my domain name as well. What happens is that the moment I hit sonar.mydomain.com it reroutes to the IP address.

I believe bitnami uses apache2 to serve sonar, and there might be settings there that I can use. But I have not been able to find the right config file and even if I found one my apache chops are rudimentary at best. Anyone who has used bitnami sonar on AWS might know how to configure this. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

To configure the domain in the Bitnami instances you can run

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/apps/sonarqube/bnconfig --machine_hostname YOUR_DOAMIN
```

Rename this tool so that it does not change again at boot time

```
sudo mv /opt/bitnami/apps/sonarqube/bnconfig /opt/bitnami/apps/sonarqube/bnconfig.disabled
```

You can check this in the documentation of Bitnami https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/apps/sonarqube/administration/configure-domain/

Comment: thanks, @ibone for responding. I did that already but for some odd reason the server still sticks to the IP address instead of the url.

Comment: Did you change the configuration of Apache to something similar to the following lines? 


`<VirtualHost _default_:80>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(localhost|127.0.0.1)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
...

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(localhost|127.0.0.1)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com$1 [R=permanent,L]
...`

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=amiuttv8BEw&feature=emb_logo